# CocoaPods config doesn't go far enough

Tags: cocoapods, xcode8

I have a large-ish project that I'm finally trying to add CocoaPods to, and I'm having some problems. This is a really old project (7 years old) that has grown and grown over the years.

It is configured like the following, because sometimes we want to build multi-language versions of the app, sometimes we want to build a watch version of the app, and sometimes we want to build an iPad version of the app.

Also, it is imperative that I be able to build this using our build script, which is custom crafted.

[image: project summary]

Let's called the blacked-out word "MyProject".

Two problems:

1) So I follow all the steps to convert my project to cocoapods, and want to compile the MyProject target. I get errors complaining that the CocoaPods library code I want to use (MBProgressHUD is my first to move over) isn't there. I AM USING THE WORKSPACE AND NOT THE PROJECT. What I have to do is "Manage Schemes", show the Pods-MyProject scheme, build that scheme, and then go back and build the MyProject scheme. That works. But from how I read what everyone else is doing, that shouldn't be necessary. How do I fix this?

2) Looking at the project.pbxproj file, I noticed that only MyProject_AW WatchKit App got a library file (called  libPods-MyProject_AW WatchKit App.a), but none of the other targets did. Maybe that is why I'm having problem 1)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It may be helpful to set your pods architecture build setting from 'active only to no', build for generic and then try again

Comment: I'll take a look at that, thanks!